# how can I download org.apache.http packages

Tags: java, android

I am beginner in android application development. I was trying database connection and I get error in my code for the following packages. Please tell me where can I download these packages , how to use them?

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are using,

**1. Android Studio :**

then add this dependancy in your build.gradle at application level :

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1' 
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
```

**2. Eclipse :**

Download this library as a jar and put it in your libs folder

HttpCore : http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.1

HttpClient : 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5

Answer (score 1):

You can download it from here: [Apache HttpComponents](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/download.html)

Comment: thanks .what exactly should i download in this httpClient and how to use?

Comment: You have to download the .jar file. After download it, you have to right click on your project and select build path. A window will be displayed so there  you have to go to "libraries" and add a new user library. In that library you have to add your jar.