# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity

Tags: java, apache, servlets

I am building a Dynamic web project using TomCat 9, and setting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.HttpEntity.

My project is make a Oauth call, which takes client ID and Secret from UI(index.html) ---> servlet(outPutValue.java) ----> Addition.java where it makes a call to API with the client crede and should get access token, but now it throws below error if I add IO exception handling

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [controller.outPutValue] in
>   context with path [/Calculator] threw exception [Servlet execution
>   threw an exception] with root cause java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.http.HttpEntity    at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1269)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1104)
>     at controller.outPutValue.doPost(outPutValue.java:48)

Addition Code --

```
public class addition {
private int first;
private int second;
public int getFirst() {
    return first;
}
public void setFirst(int first) {
    this.first = first;
}
public int getSecond() {
    return second;
}
public void setSecond(int second) {
    this.second = second;
}


public void add(String first,String second) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {

System.out.println("This is after coming to addition");


HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://api-XYZ.com/oauth2/token");

    post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    post.setHeader("Accept","application/json");
    post.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en");

List <NameValuePair> body = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_id",first));
body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("client_secret",second));
body.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type","client_credentials"));

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(body));
HttpResponse response=null;
response = client.execute(post);
System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

String auth_resp=null;
auth_resp = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
System.out.println(auth_resp);

}
```

Str--- PFA[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kym0t.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I download org.apache.http packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32309780/how-can-i-download-org-apache-http-packages)

Comment: not enough code... is that add method in the same class as your pojo?

Comment: @Jason I do have HttpCore, HttpClient already in the Lib.

Comment: @jonathan Added the class distribution PFA in the question.